# Images cannot load after firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I made my portfolio website with NextJS and React, then use Firebase to host it.
However, the logo icon was gone when the site deployed.

[image]

I can't find the solution to deal with it. Below is my folder structure

[image][image]

Or I need to set something in the nextConfig.js?

[image]

Hope can get help, many thanks.

Comment: Sorry I know Vue, Angular, Svelte but no React. XD

Comment: Sad, my bad luck :(